# GKE - Where I need to specify "“cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "true”"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

In the Google Cloud Platform environment, I am facing errors like `**Pod is blocking scale down because it has local storage**` and `**Pod is blocking scale down because it doesn't have enough Pod Disruption Budget**`

Got an answer to solve this, I need to set the annotation while creating the pod that is `cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: "true"`.

I have two kind of yaml files in GCP environment: "*Deployment*" and for "*HorizontalPodAutoscaler*".

Can you please guide me where to specify `cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: "true"`?

**HorizontalPodAutoscaler yaml file**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa-{{ include "graphql.fullname" . }}
spec:=
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ include "graphql.fullname" . }}
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 30
```

**deployment yaml file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "graphql.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "graphql.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "graphql.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "graphql.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "graphql.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      volumes:
        {{- range $var := .Values.secretvolumes}}
        - name: {{ $var.volumename }}
          secret:
            secretName: {{ $var.secretname }}
        {{- end }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.full_digest_url }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command: {{ .Values.image.command }}
          args:
            {{- range $index, $arg := .Values.image.args }}
            - {{ $arg }}
            {{- end }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /.well-known/apollo/server-health
              port: http
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          env:
            - name: GAE_VERSION
              value: {{ $.Values.image.full_digest_url }}
            {{- range $key, $value := .Values.env}}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              value: {{ $value| quote }}
            {{- end }}
            {{- range $var := .Values.envsecrets}}
            - name: {{ $var.name }}
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ $var.secret }}
                  key: {{ $var.key }}
            {{- end }}
          volumeMounts:
            {{- range $var := .Values.secretvolumes}}
            - name: {{ $var.volumename }}
              mountPath: /var/secrets/{{ $var.secretname }}
              readOnly: true
            {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

Comment: You can use the `kubectl patch deployment` to add the annotation, go to step No. 5 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html) and [here](https://fabianlee.org/2021/09/19/kubernetes-adding-and-removing-pod-template-annotations-using-kubectl/) for 2 reference guides.

Comment: If the answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your deployment manifest, under `{"spec": {"template":{"metadata"`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "graphql.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "graphql.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "graphql.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "graphql.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "graphql.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
      annotations:
        cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: "true"
```